# Highlight text of a DIV as user types characters in an input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen many posts pertaining to highlighting text in a DIV using javascript, but none do quite what I'm looking for.

What I need to do is highlight the text within a specific DIV, character by character as the user enters the search term.  Conversely, as the user backspaces or deletes characters, I need to "de-highlight" the text of the same DIV.

I imagine this has already been done somewhere by someone, but I have not yet found a post here or from Google that behaves exactly as I need.

Any feedback is appreciated.

this code executes as user types characters into an input field.  The problem with it is that in some instances, it inserts the string " " into the table as I type and I don't know why, so I'm searching for a different solution.

Thanks for your feedback!

```
function filterTable(Stxt, table) {
     dehighlight(document.getElementById(table));
     if (Stxt.value.length > 0)
       highlight(Stxt.value.toLowerCase(), document.getElementById(table));
  }

  function dehighlight(container) {
     for (var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
       var node = container.childNodes[i];
       if (node.attributes && node.attributes['class'] && node.attributes['class'].value == 'highlighted') {
           node.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(
           document.createTextNode(node.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")),node.parentNode);
           return;
       } else if (node.nodeType != 3) {
           dehighlight(node);
       }
     }
  }

  function highlight(Stxt, container) {
    for (var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = container.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var data = node.data;
            var data_low = data.toLowerCase();
            if (data_low.indexOf(Stxt) >= 0) {
                var new_node = document.createElement('span');
                node.parentNode.replaceChild(new_node, node);
                var result;
                while ((result = data_low.indexOf(Stxt)) != -1) {
                    new_node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.substr(0, result)));
                    new_node.appendChild(create_node(
                    document.createTextNode(data.substr(result, Stxt.length))));
                    data = data.substr(result + Stxt.length);
                    data_low = data_low.substr(result + Stxt.length);
                }
                new_node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
            }
        } else {
            highlight(Stxt, node);
        }
    }
  }

  function create_node(child) {
    var node = document.createElement('span');
    node.setAttribute('class', 'highlighted');
    node.attributes['class'].value = 'highlighted';
    node.appendChild(child);
    return node;
  }
```

Comment: so the user is copying (by typing) the text that is in the div, and as that text is copied it gets highlighted?

Comment: Does the div only contain text or does it have sub elements? If it contains only <p> than the script doesn't have to be that complicated but if it has something like he<strong>llo</strong> then it's hard to match "hello" without taking out all the sub element (using innerText/textContent). Is the cursor focused on a particular element when this needs to happen or is the cursor in a text input?

Comment: so there would be an input field and the user types a search term in it.  as the user types, if matches are found within a specified DIV, they are highlighted character by character as the user types and highlights removed as user deletes characters.  The DIV would contain an HTML table with text only.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code of what you have already done, or a sample website that has the said features?

Comment: so you basically want it to work exactly like chrome's find, except applied only to a specific div rather than the entire page.

Comment: @smerny exactly correct.  The only real difference would be that the input field would be integrated already into the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be easily done with a regular expression to change the div's content. Here's a simple implementation :

```
var s = document.getElementById('s');    // your input
var div = document.getElementById('a');  // the div to change
var t = a.textContent || a.innerText;
s.onkeyup = function(){
   div.innerHTML = this.value
   ? t.replace(new RegExp('('+this.value+')','ig'), '<span class=highlight>$1</span>')
   : t;
};
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/iriwaw/2/edit) (click "Run with JS")

---

**EDIT :**

This more sophisticated version works even if you have tables and stuff :

```
var s = document.getElementById('s');
var div = document.getElementById('a'); 

function changeNode(n, r, f) {
  f=n.childNodes; for(c in f) changeNode(f[c], r);
  if (n.data) {
    f = document.createElement('span');
    f.innerHTML = n.data.replace(r, '<span class=found>$1</span>');
    n.parentNode.insertBefore(f, n);
    n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
  }
}
s.onkeyup = function(){
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('found');
  while (spans.length) {
    var p = spans[0].parentNode;
    p.innerHTML = p.textContent || p.innerText;
  }
  if (this.value) changeNode(
    div, new RegExp('('+this.value+')','gi')
  );
};
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/iriwaw/3/edit)** (click "Run with JS")

Comment: This would be the perfect solution, except the table format cannot be altered.  The layout of the table must remain as is and just the text can be highlighted as the user types.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: So don't change the div : apply this to the table cells instead.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the table is built dynamically, so I wrapped it in a DIV to limit the region that is searched.  The contents inside the DIV are a table and that is what needs to be searched.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Lane I made a version working for any kind of html. See edit.

Comment: I'm getting a js error.  as I type, for some reason after the first character is typed, the object for p.textContent is null.  Not sure why, but I'm trying to look into it.

Comment: @Lane What's your browser ? I tested it on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: sadly, i'm forced to use IE9

Comment: Do [this version](http://jsbin.com/iriwaw/5/edit) work for you ? I can't easily test on IE.

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not supported in IE apparently.  I've got it working (sort of) but still getting object null or undefined error on p.innerHTML = p.textContent || p.innerText;  Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: This function should be supported, according to the MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: thank you Denys I was also looking for this, do you know how can I edit the code so it differentiates between lower case and uppercase letters? Regards -

Comment: @jcslzr My regular expression is passed flags: the `'ig'` part. Remove the `i`  (ie, use only `'g'`) and it will be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

My [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library has support for this, although I admit it's quite a large script for just this one use.

Demo: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo that uses regex.

```
// Input element
var input = document.getElementById("highlighter"), 
    // Text container element
    divText = document.getElementById("text"),
    // using textContent property if it exists
    textProp = ("textContent" in divText) ? "textContent" : "innerText",
    // Getting text to discard html tags (delete line 6 and use divText.innerHTML if you want to keep the HTML tags)
    originalText = divText[textProp];

function handler(){
    // if Input.value is empty clear the highlights
    if(!this.value){
        divText.innerHTML = originalText;
        return true;
    }
    // Regex to group the matches, with tags 'global' and 'case insensitive'
    var regex = new RegExp("("+this.value+")", "ig");
    // replace text with the new one ($1 refers to first group matched by regex)
    divText.innerHTML = originalText.replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");

};
// adding listener to input.. IE uses attachEvent method
input.addEventListener("keyup", handler, false);
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/HDqeN/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let keywords = $("#highlight").html(); //get replace text
let textBody = $("#textBody"); //replace body

//create regular expression //text without case change
let custfilter = new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "ig");

//replace with highlight
textBody.html(textBody.html().replace(custfilter, "<b>$1</b>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="textBody">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>

<span id="highlight">IPSUM</span>
```