# Angular 2 - Highlight text of a DIV as user types characters in an input field

Tags: angular

I am trying to give to my users some feedback on my angular 2 application by highlighting text from a div as they type in an input.

This would be the perfect solution:

[Highlight text of a DIV as user types characters in an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951214/highlight-text-of-a-div-as-user-types-characters-in-an-input-field)

However, with the Angular2's different approach for DOM Manipulation I haven't been able to do it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div [innerHTML]="highlighted"></div>
<input [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="updateHighlight()" name="high">
```

```
class MyComponent {
  this.allText = 'lorem ipsum ...';
  text = '';
  highlighted = '';
  updateHighlight() {
    this.highlighted = this.text
        ? allText.replace(new RegExp('('+this.text+')','ig'), 
            '<span class=highlight>$1</span>')
        : allText;        
  }
}
```

Comment: I only had to change allText with this.allText and add encapsulation.ViewEncapsulation.None to the component to get the class to work with my css stylesheet, thank you for your answer!