# How to highlight the search text in div

Tags: html, angular

I am working on angular. I want to highlight the "Searchtxt" in html, Searchtxt is a variable which holds the value of searchbar.
Eg: Searchtxt="ProductName"

HTML code :

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let cmp of ApiResult;let i = index">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="{{cmp.pkCategoryMaster}}">
        <h1 class="side_header">{{cmp.categoryName}}</h1>
        <div class="subcat hp-subcat22 HP_1_1" *ngFor="let cmpsub of ApiResult[i].subCategory;let j = index">
            <h2>{{cmpsub.SubCategoryName}}</h2>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let cmpProd of ApiResult[i].subCategory[j].ProductCategory **|search: searchtxt** ;">
                    <a (click)="NavigateByHome(cmpProd.PkProductCategoryMaster);">
                        {{cmpProd.ProductCategory **| highlight: searchtxt**}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS code :

```
var searchtxt=localStorage.getItem("productCategoryName");
```

Pipe.ts :

```
transform(ProductCategory: any, searchText: string): any[] {

    if (!ProductCategory) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
        return ProductCategory;
    }

    const value = ProductCategory.replace(
        searchText, `<div style='background-color:yellow'>${searchText}</div>`);
    console.log('value', value);

    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951214/highlight-text-of-a-div-as-user-types-characters-in-an-input-field).

Comment: Please post `highlight` pipe `.ts` code.

Comment: @Nicolae sorry but i didn't understand that solution.

Comment: @hrdkisback i added the pipe.ts.

Comment: Can you create and share a stackbiltz

Comment: @AdritaSharma sorry i can't ,i don't know how to create stackbiltz.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just applying a style to items in the list that match a particular value. You could just use ngClass to conditionally apply a CSS class that you define for the component.

component.scss

```
.highlight {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let cmpProd of ApiResult[i].subCategory[j].ProductCategory **|search:searchtxt** ;">
  <a (click)="NavigateByHome(cmpProd.PkProductCategoryMaster);"
     [ngClass]="{ 'highlight' : cmpProd.ProductCategory === searchTxt }">
    {{cmpProd.ProductCategory}}
  </a>
</li>
```

I wouldn't use a pipe to output html. You've already seen that you have to disable a security check which should act as a warning that this isn't the right way. If you want something that is reusable then I would write a component rather than a pipe but if all it does is change the background colour based on this condition then it's probably overkill.